Reset issue while issuing commands to SD card
I am busy with a project where I'm trying to make a custom flashcard for the Gameboy (for more details, refer to https://efacdev.nl/projects/ecgc). For the flashcard, I am trying to load games from an SD card for the Gameboy to play. The cartridge is based on an Lattice FPGA.
I am currently in the process of writing code for communicating with said SD card. However, I ran into the issue of the system resetting every time I issue a valid command to the SD card. I have written a program to read and write to a given address on the cartridge's memory map, which I use to test registers in the cartridge's FPGA. I use this to write to registers of a SPI controller to communicate with the SD card via SPI. After writing the final byte of the SD command frame (CRC7 + end bit), the Gameboy either freezes or resets.
Now, I am guessing this is a hardware issue since I am a software/firmware engineer and don't have much experience making hardware. I first thought that something was browning out so I measured the different VCC rails in the cartridge (1V2, 1V8, 3V3 and 5V), but I don't measure any sudden voltage drops. Maybe I am not measuring right, I am grasping at straws.
To aid any helpers, I have here a diagram of the cartridge's hardware. It shows all functional hardware and what interfaces with what.

And also one on the firmware on the FPGA.
Here, the red blocks are external to the FPGA, blue blocks are entities inside the FPGA and yellow/orange arrows/blocks are interconnects.

Some other random facts that may help:

I have seen the Gameboy's reset pin pulse in some tests. However, I think that this is just a symptom of the problem. It seems like the Gameboy program corrupts, then the program runs wild and by chance writes into one of the FPGA's control registers. I have one which pulses the Gameboy reset.
I have seen one of the other chip selects on the SPI bus pulse low in one test. Looking at the firmware, this could only be due to a runaway pointer writing into the chip select register. Or maybe this could be due to a brownout, where the VCCIO drops below acceptable levels and turns off the pin. But again, I am speculating here.
The issue only occurs when writing a valid command to the SD card. If I mess up the command CRC for example, the Gameboy does not crash. I am thinking that maybe the command wakes something up inside the SD card, resulting in a large sudden current draw which causes VCC to drop. But again, I cannot measure any voltage drop.
After the crash, if I reset the cartridge properly, re-enable the SPI core and start reading from the SD card, I do get the expected response from it (in the case of CMD0, this would be R0). So it seems the SD card and the SPI core work fine and something at the Gameboy side is failing (this might be the FPGA, bus transceivers, reset buffer, idk).

So yeah, I'm at a complete lost. Does anyone have an idea what the issue might be? Or have any tips in what I could look at? Anything is welcome. I have exhausted al the possible causes I thought of and am currently just trying random stuff out in the hope that it works, which isn't the most efficient way of doing things to say the least.
I have the schematics publicized on Github (https://github.com/elialm/ecgc-hardware/releases/tag/v2.0). The only relevant modification I made to these is an extra electrolytic 100uF decoupling capacitor on the SD card VCC and ground. And for anyone that can read it, the FPGA firmware is available at https://github.com/elialm/ecgc-firmware and the code running on the Gameboy is at https://github.com/elialm/ecgc-boot.

There is a long trace, probably above 50 nH, from the SD card supply pin to the decoupling capacitor. This introduces ugly problems. Can you add a small 10 uF / 6.3V ceramic SMD capacitor close to the supply pin, probably better mounted on the other side below the card connector for comparison?

You cannot have 100uF capacitor on SD_VCC rail, some SD recovery functions rely on power-off timing, and the connection will fail. Without SD protocol analyzer you cannot meaningfully debug SD issues.

@Jens I have tried that, but the issue persists. I've connected it in the place of C33 (where originally the 100nF decoupling capacitor was connected). I see now that the schematic implies that C17 is the decoupling capacitor, which is not the case. I'll fix it in a next release.

@Ale..chenski I have seen designs with a 47uF + 100nF capacitor, which seemed logical. My thought was "100uF should do the trick", but that failed me. However, I fail to understand how improper power-off timing would cause my issue. And buying a dedicated analyser sounds expensive though...


So yeah, I'm at a complete lost. Does anyone have an idea what the
issue might be?

It sounds like some of the issue might be external signals not being clocked in correctly. Or clock synchronization between the FPGA and external signals.
Here are some suggestions:

Create external debug ports that you can connect a logic analyzer into the FPGA to monitor specific registers, you may have to blue wire a 0.1" header if you don't have anything like this already, You probably have already done this.

Make sure you are using a dual rank synchronizer (which you are probably doing but worth mentioning) FPGA input synchronisation

Do a test with each hardware block individually with some kind of test fixture on the FPGA, write known values to the SD card and then read them back, yeah this is time consuming, but you could locate the point of failure.

Make sure your power rails are being brought up correctly if you have an FPGA and SD card, check the power section and see if they need timing when the unit is turned on. The SD card should have something like 0.1uF and 10uF not 100uF. Check the voltage for the slightest dip.

Check the grounds, check different grounding points between modules with a scope (do a differential measurement) the potential should be zero or a few mV, if it isn't even on short timescales then you need to improve the grounding.



The schematic shows a JTAG connector for the Lattice LFXP2-8E-5MN132C FPGA. Perhaps the Lattice Diamond Reveal tool could be used as the FPGA on-chip debug tool, transferring the trace data to a PC over JTAG, without needing to connect an external logic analyzer.

Yes, but that means the values will be a bit more removed from reality as they are registered and clocked by the jtag.

@VoltageSpike I'll try your suggestions. 1 & 2 are already done. I'll dive into the datasheet again to check for power rail timings. Then change the capacitor values and check the groundings. If that all fails, I'll try suggestion 3 (the most time consuming...). Thanks for the suggestions, I'll award you the reputation.
